# Django : matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I am getting error while creating an instance of ModelForm in DJango.
I am not always facing the issue but sometimes it work fine and sometimes it  gives me error.

ModelFOrm code :

```
class ClientinfoForm(ModelForm):
    Account_Name = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
    class Meta:
        model = AccountDescription
        fields = ['Account_Name','short_Name','group_Master_Project_Code','account_Logo','vertical','client_Website','client_Revenue','Employee_Count','client_Industry_Segment','delivery_Manager_Mail','project_Manager_Mail']
        labels = {'client_Revenue':'Client Revenue(in USD Billion)','vertical':'Industry Vertical'}
        help_texts = {'client_revenue' : '(In Billion USD)' }
```

views.py code

```
def save_client_info(request):
    fm = ClientinfoForm(request.POST, instance = AccountDescription.objects.get(Account_Name = acc_name),files = request.FILES or None)
    save_form(request,fm)


def clientinfo(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("inside form")
            save_client_info(request)
        global s4_option
        s4_option = AccountDescription.objects.filter(Account_Name = acc_name).values('s4_data')
        s4_option = s4_option[0]['s4_data']
        accdata = AccountDescription.objects.filter(Account_Name = acc_name)
        clientdata = ClientinfoForm(instance = AccountDescription.objects.get(Account_Name = acc_name))
        return render(request, 'AccountData/ClientInfo.html',{'name' : 'clientinfo','form':clientdata,'acntdata':accdata,'content':editoption})
```

Sometimes, when I save it works perfectly fine but sometimes it give matching query doesn't exist.

Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
instance = AccountDescription.objects.get(Account_Name = acc_name)
```

in `save_client_info` function to something like

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

instance = get_object_or_404(AccountDescription, Account_Name=acc_name)
```

Note: I assumed that you've defined `acc_name` properly before this line somewhere in your codes.

Because there will be always some situations that this record does not exists and there for Django will raise a `does not exist` error type. Or you can also return a desired response if this query doesn't exist in your database like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

try:
    fm = ClientinfoForm(request.POST, instance = AccountDescription.objects.get(Account_Name = acc_name),files = request.FILES or None)
except AccountDescription.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse("Requested account does not exist") # or any other responses
```

Comment: But the record(Account) always exist in the DB. for the same record if I update the record, it shows Query doesn't exist. but when I reload it works fine.

for eg. let's say I edit for account X, if I edit the form and save the form most of the time it run okay but for the same account sometimes it gives "query doesn't exist error."